# C++ class method to stop current thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a thread pool that reads command objects from a queue. Each command object is an implementation of an abstract command class with a single execute() method, i.e. the command pattern.

I want to implement a command that makes the thread stop itself, i.e. the execute() method stops the current thread. Usually I would just return from the thread function, but I need to stop the thread from the execute() method.

What is the best way to do this? I can use detach or destroy, but the main program calls join on all threads and I’m not sure if it will work. Assume everything the thread has access to has been unlocked.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the thread from the execute method"?

Comment: @PasserBy thread calls command.execute(), which stops / kills the thread.

Comment: You could do `if(command.execute() == status::quit) return;` or something

Comment: Such command is called *poisson*. Just check whether a poisson is received, if so, return.

Comment: Killing a thread arbitrarily can be problematic. At the very least you would want the thread to get a chance to unwind it's stack.

Comment: A "sandbox" code would be helpful to give better advices ;-)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't portably terminate or stop a std::thread in any way other than either returning from the initial function or terminating the entire process. If you don't want to change the signature of execute(), the command object can have a retval member that can be accessed after running execute().

You shouldn't detach the thread if it will be joined later. Also, keep in mind that a non-detached thread that has finished execution will hang on to some resources until it's joined. It's probably not much, but you don't want to constantly create threads without cleaning them up.